# How do you write in the header column for CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7

```
def write_vt(d, filename):
    f = open(filename, 'w')
```

I am supposed to open the new file in write mode and then write in the header column, then use a for loop to add strings of data into the file. But I just can't figure out how to do this...

Original filename is `votes.csv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, depending on your data and what tools you're willing to use:

## a) Writing the CSV row by row with lists and a header

```
import csv


data_list = [
    ["Russia", "Moscow", "Russian"],
    ["US", "Washington, D.C.", "English"],
    ["Colombia", "Bogotá", "Spanish"]
]
header = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

def write_csv_from_lists(data, header, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(header) # write header
        for row in data:
            csv_writer.writerow(row) # write each row

write_csv_from_lists(data_list, header, "file1.csv")
```

### file1.csv

```
col1,col2,col3
Russia,Moscow,Russian
US,"Washington, D.C.",English
Colombia,Bogotá,Spanish
```

## b) Writing the CSV row by row with dicts and a header

```
import csv


data_dict = [
    {"col1": "Russia", "col2": "Moscow", "col3": "Russian"},
    {"col1": "US", "col2": "Washington, D.C.", "col3": "English"},
    {"col1": "Colombia", "col2": "Bogotá", "col3": "Spanish"}
]
header = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

def write_csv_from_dicts(data, header, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as csv_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=header)
        dict_writer.writeheader() # write header
        for row in data:
            dict_writer.writerow(row) # write each row

write_csv_from_dicts(data_dict, header, "file2.csv")
```

### file2.csv

```
col1,col2,col3
Russia,Moscow,Russian
US,"Washington, D.C.",English
Colombia,Bogotá,Spanish
```

## c) Writing the CSV with pandas

```
import pandas as pd


data_dict = [
    {"col1": "Russia", "col2": "Moscow", "col3": "Russian"},
    {"col1": "US", "col2": "Washington, D.C.", "col3": "English"},
    {"col1": "Colombia", "col2": "Bogotá", "col3": "Spanish"}
]

def write_csv_pandas(data, filename):

    pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(filename, index=False)

write_csv_pandas(data_dict, "file3.csv")
```

### file3.csv

```
col1,col2,col3
Russia,Moscow,Russian
US,"Washington, D.C.",English
Colombia,Bogotá,Spanish
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to add the header:

```
header = "col1,col2,col3"
with open('file.csv','w') as my_csv:
    my_csv.write(header+'\n')
```

concerning filling your CSV with data, it will depend on the original data you will use as source.